# What's the easiest way to detect what signals are being sent to a process and from whom? Linux

Tags: linux, signals, yocto

I'm getting this signal on a program that i have on a Yocto project image:  "Exiting on signal 1"

And i don't know which process is sending it, and i need to find out due to my application keeps getting closed every time it opens and i don't know why.

Unfortunately I can't use ltrace or strace because none of them are installed in this image. Already tried them both.

What could i do to find this issue? Maybe a bash script that keeps listening for all the signals?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `strace` command to trace the system calls and signals being sent to a process.

`strace -p <pid> -e signal`

output

```
SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=4842, si_uid=1000}
```

`si_pid` will show you the process ID that send a signal.

Note: The following method using strace will not work if the process has been forcefully killed (for example, using the kill -9 command).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use ltrace or strace like I said on the post.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't read your text carefully.
I don't know if there is a Bash script available for this task or not,but you can trace the events of process using debugfs

`cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing;echo <pid> > set_event_pid;cat trace | grep signal_generate;
`
You can also filter specific events in this way.
`echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/signal/signal_generate/enable`
For more information, you can refer to the following link.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/trace/events.html